# Is there a way to set {matchCase:false} globally when using contains?

Tags: cypress, case-insensitive

So i'm using cypress and most of my selector is using contains

So instead of using {matchCase:false} in every contains is there a way to set it globally?

Answer (score 3):

There's no global configuration setting for what you need, but it's a good idea and I recommend you raise it with Cypress as an enhancement. You might get it done as part of the Query API enhancement.

In the meantime, if you want something now you can take a **composition** approach.

Create a case-insensitive version of `cy.contains()` based on the built-in one.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('contains_i', {prevSubject: 'optional'},
  (subject, filter, text, options = {}) => {

    if (typeof text === 'object') {
      options = text
      text = filter
      filter = undefined
    }

    if (!options.matchCase) {
      // allow true to be passed but default to false
      options.matchCase = false
    }

    return cy.contains(subject, filter, text, options)
})
```

Then you can globally replace in VS Code using `Ctrl-Shift-H`

[image]

which will do both parent `cy.contains()` and child `cy.get().contains()` instances.

You can preview and remove certain change instances.

Answer (score 0):

Jennifer Shehane (an Engineering Manager at Cypress) [recommends overriding the `.contains()` command:](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6564#issuecomment-591845915)

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('contains', (originalFn, subject, filter, text, options = {}) => {
  // determine if a filter argument was passed
  if (typeof text === 'object') {
    options = text
    text = filter
    filter = undefined
  }

  options.matchCase = false

  return originalFn(subject, filter, text, options)
})
```

Additionally, [you could use a case-insensitive regex matcher](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) instead of just a string, although you would need to do this in every instance:

```js
cy.contains(/MyStRiNg/i);
// matches "mystring", "MYSTRING", and any combination of uppercase/lowercase inbetween
```

Comment: It should be noted that v12 currently does not allow command overwriting. Here is the Gh issue. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25078

Comment: Oof - hadn't seen that (I'm not currently on a web project :'( and my last one was using Cypress 10) but that'd be frustrating, considering this is far from the first time Jennifer or Gleb have recommended overwriting a query.

Comment: Yes, it can be troublesome for new release users who rely plugins such as cypress-if. The discussion says there will be talks on considering an alternative such as an API to do the overwriting. It all depends on how many comment on the ticket asking for this feature to come back.